# Acting nice for karma's sake?

Tags: karma

If I recall correctly, karma is constituted of two parts - action and intention. Which means if one wishes to "gain" positive karma, one would have to conduct a positive action AND do so with a positive mind. With that being said, if I were to help an old lady to cross the street for the sole purpose of obtaining good karma, am I going to get good karma?

Answer (score 3):

This is a triple win in term of accumulating and strengthening the effectiveness of the karmic action:

1. Being nice
2. Knowing being nice has consequences
3. Acting knowing there are consequences

When doing good, believing in Karma and knowing there are consequences, reinforce the good results.

Comment: Sadhu, sadhu,  Upasaka

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of obtaining good karma, one would in most cases accumulate more good than for any other common purpose, yes. "Just" for the sake of doing good is a very noble intention, householder Timothy Hung.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are exercising the muscle of kindness. Eventually the action will become more natural.

Comment: You can comment instead.

Comment: @Swapnil Short answers are permitted -- and if it is an answer I'd prefer it posted as an answer than as a comment (I often even delete short-answer-posted-as-a-comment to encourage people to post answers instead). A longer answer is sometimes better, e.g. an answer that's "based on" something -- some experience (i.e. "something which happened to you personally"), and/or a reference (to scripture).

Comment: @ChrisW I thought it should be comment cause of flagged as short answer.

Comment: @Swapnil Was it flagged, are you using the "Review queue?" Thank you! But anyway there's [When my answer is short, shall I post it as a comment instead?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1589/254) -- also [When shouldn't I comment?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says, "Comments are not recommended for ... Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer"

Comment: Yes I used "review queue" . Thanks for mentioned links for short answer.

Answer (score 1):

Karma is how this world behaves. As an example in general how world behave is ; if we change the state of a weight (put a stone from the ground on the table) to a more unstable position (being on the table is more unstable than being on the ground) what would happen? Once its got a chance it comes to a stable position right? You can name this as gravity or any other concept in Science. The same model is happening in Karma too.

By helping a lady to cross the road you are changing the state, and once the nature got a chance it gives you similar thing back. But main thing to remember is that ‘chethana han bikkha wè kamman wadami’ means thought (intention) is the karma. So if you do this without the intention of really helping that lady, you will not get similar help in future. The intention you meant here may cause you to be used by someone else (as return karma) to get what they want while you will feel some easiness.

Answer (score 0):

It will still be positive, but not as beneficial as if it was done selflessly.

Comment: for the sake of doing good is selfish perse?

Comment: As stated in the question, of course it is.  Generosity is always self giving, not self building.

Comment: Is self-giving then not a way toward a more refined buulding up of existence, householder? Does one not give strengh by mind, signs and deeds, one time? And if it is for the sake of that, a better self?

Comment: The purpose of accumulating good kamma has not mentioned, or? Of course one can assume this or that heading, tendecy of one, but that would be assume behind the words, or?